# Why can't I flag a low-voted, closed question for deletion?

Tags: support, flags

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930890/we-prefer-questions-that-can-be-answered-not-just-discussed was voted-down and closed quickly, because it was obviously just vandalism.

I was going to flag this question to be deleted, but I can't (the Flag Question button is disabled).

I can't see why not — can anyone explain?

<del>**Screenshot**</del>

> **Note**: idiotic screenshot removed.  My screenshot showed that I had not selected a sub-reason, however, prior to refreshing, the button was still disabled even with a sub-reason of **"it needs ♦ moderator attention"** selected.  I was trying to select **"very low quality"**.

**Edit:** Thank you all for your detailed eyes.  However, this was a gigantic **screenshot fail**.  I had selected one of sub-reasons originally, and it was still disabled.  I refreshed the page to double check and take the screenshot.  Maybe it was just a glitch the first time, because clearly my "double-checking" was flawed.

Comment: It's deleted now ;)

Comment: Asking on Meta also has a tendency to focus the Eye of Sauron rather quickly.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - *doh* - see updates.

Comment: In my answer, see the repro steps for a scenario where the option may be selected but button is still disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** You can reproduce the issue that you mentioned in your question.

Here are the steps:

1. On the flagging popup, select `other` option.
2. Type in some description but don't exceed the minimum limit.
3. Now, change your mind and go for `very low quality` option. Note: You need to click on some particular location to have the option `very low quality` selected and still have the **Flag Question** button disabled.
4. Refer the below screen where I have the `very low quality` option selected but **Flag Question** is disabled.

[image: Repro]

It seems that you have not selected either `very low quality` or `other` to enable the **Flag Question** button. If you select `Other`, you need to provide a description.

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 5):

You need to click one of the two child radio buttons for it to be activated. Like my flag on this question:

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - see updates to question.  I blew it on the screenshot.  I had originally done what you suggest and it was still disabled.  I took the screenshot after refreshing.  And, now that it is *really* gone, I can't double check.